# ¿Cómo abrir un archivo excel desde un combobox? C#

Tags: c#, excel

Ando mi problema es el siguiente, trato de abrir un archivo excel de una carpeta con botón, pero en, la carpeta hay multiples excel, la idea es elegir el excel que se desea abrir con un combobox para posteriormente abrirlo con un botón, pero no me ocurre como es posible, o que relleñar en el espacio del botón,

Mi código: el cual muestra funcional la forma de abrir en la carpeta creo que me falta una forma de abrir archivos excel aunque no se como

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string path = @"C:\Users\Nero\Desktop\test";
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("File Name");
            table.Columns.Add("File Path");

            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            foreach (FileInfo fileInf in dir.GetFiles())
            {
                table.Rows.Add(fileInf.Name, path + "\\" + fileInf.Name);
            }

            comboBox1.DataSource = table;
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "File Name";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "File Path";
        }
```

Comment: si ya tienes el path del excel solo es como hacerle Process.Start("Aqui le pasas el path y listo");

Comment: la idea es que al seleccionar uno de los archivos del combobox se pueda, con un boton abrir dichos archivos, ahora si nose si refiere a que abran seleccionando un combobox? por process start entiendo algo como : ```Process.Start("C:\\")  ``` pero la dentro de un boton, ahora so no seria una ruta mas especifica, en mi codigo la ruta que poseo es una carpeta que posee multiples excel , la idea es que al seleccionar uno pueda abrirlo, y en eso no tengo idea de como se podria hacer

Comment: y porque no abrirlo al seleccionarlos desde el combobox? cual es la direfencia entre hacerlo desde un boton?

Comment: que al seleccionar el combobox, se abra los excel?

Comment: Tal vez quieras mejorar la pregunta. La respuesta ya te muestra cómo obtener el nombre del archivo desde el DropDown, y cómo abrir Excel desde C#.

Comment: abrir seria lo que necesito, y es lo que pregunte solo que quiero abrir los archivos cargados de una carpeta, los cuales fueron cargados o sus nombre puesto en el combobox

Answer (score 2):

No está tan claro lo que preguntas.

Si deseas:

1. Llenar un DropDown con los nombres de archivo: Hay mil maneras. Una es la siguiente:

Creas una clase

```
 public class Archivo 
    {
      public string NombreArchivo {get;set;}
      public string Ruta {get;set;}
    }
```

Debes obtener los  nombes y las rutas. De acuerdo a tu código, ya lo puedes obtener.

```
  var dataSource = new List<Archivo>();
  dataSource.Add(new Archivo() { NombreArchivo = "GastosMercadeo",
               Ruta= "C:\Reportes\GastosMercadeo.xls" });
  dataSource.Add(new Archivo() { NombreArchivo = "RegistroLlamadas",
               Ruta= "C:\Reportes\RegistroLlamadas.xls" });
  dataSource.Add(new Archivo() { NombreArchivo = "GastosOperativos",
               Ruta= "C:\Reportes\GastosOperativos.xls" });

  //realizas el databinding
  this.comboBox1.DataSource = dataSource;
  this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "NombreArchivo";
  this.comboBox1.ValueMember = "Ruta";
```

2. Deseas abrir excel con un botón:

Pasas la ruta del archivo al evento del botón "Abrir". Si tienes Excel como programa pre-determinado para abrir archivos xls, entonces utilizas

```
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\Reportes\GastosOperativos.xls");
```

Si tus xls no tienen Excel por default, puedes abrir un proceso nuevo con el nombre de la aplicación:

```
 static void AbrirArchivoExcel(string rutaDelArchivoXls)
   {
      ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
      startInfo.FileName = "EXCEL.EXE";
      startInfo.Arguments = rutaDelArchivoXls;
      Process.Start(startInfo);
   }
```

Espero te ayude

**EDIT**

Si la ruta del archivo está dentro del DropDown, puedes obtener el ítem del DropDown haciendo un cast de tipo Arichivo:

```
 public void AbrirExcel_Button(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
   {
    //Obtenemos el ítem Archivo del DropDown
    var archivoSeleccionado = (Archivo)dropDown.SelectedItem;
    //Obtenemos la ruta:
    var ruta= archivoSeleccionado.Value.ToString();       

   //Se pasa la ruta al método que abre el archivo en excel
    AbrirArchivoExcel(ruta);
    }
```

Comment: mi codigo ya puede obtener datos, de excel dentro de una carpeta me salen multiplicados x 2 si, aunque lo que pregunto es como abrir dichos excel

Comment: Como dice la respuesta, puedes utilizar el System.Diagnostics.Process.Start; o puedes utilizar el método AbrirArchivoExcel

Comment: pero el metodo de process start, debo especificar la ruta, en mi combobox mostrado, yo muestro por ejemplo todos los excel de una carpeta, y la idea que busco es como abrir el seleccionado de dicho combobox

Comment: @nerocaos. Edité la respuesta.

Comment: de esa forma puedo abrir cualquier excel dentro de la carpeta?

Comment: No he probado el código en mi máquina local, pero inténtalo tú y nos cuentas los resultados?

Comment: bueno no me funciono lo puse en un boton la idea de al seleccionar un item de combobox, este abriera dicho item, pero lamentablemente me dio error, en lo que es archivo, dropdow y al finalen abrir archivo

Comment: Nos muestras tu código, por favor?

Comment: el codigo es lo que publique, si es por lo que tenia, el boton, era mas o menos un combobox. selected item pero no funciono, y termine borrandolo

Comment: en otro proyecto, si tenia un codigo que para abrir igual excel usando excel data reader  ```FileStream fs = File.Open(ofd.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read); ```

Comment: tambien probe con un openfile dialog, pero ando confuso en su uso, ademas de que necesito seleccionar un item o un file del combobox que carga de la carpeta, todo eso para posteriormente realizar una busqueda de los datos del excel

Comment: use este metodo para abrir pero aun no me funciona```OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                comboBox1.LoadFile(ofd.FileName);
            } ```

Comment: logre abrir los excels con el siguiente codigo:                                    
```private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string filePath = (comboBox1.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItems).FullPath;
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(filePath);
            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
            Process.Start(startInfo);
      }``` pero lamentablemente no era lo que necesitaba mi idea era abrir los excels seleccionados para poder realizar una búsqueda de estos, pero sin mostrarlos

Comment: finalmente me resulto usando exceldatareader el codigo quedo algo asi ` Object FilePath = (comboBox1.SelectedValue);
            FileStream stream = File.Open(""+FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            IExcelDataReader reader;
             reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
           // reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
            
            
            reader.Close(); `